# Python: return variable from class

Tags: python, function, class, variables, return

```
from database import usernames


class names():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def name_in_use(self):
        if self.name in usernames:
            print(f"Sorry {self.name} is already taken. Please come up with a different username.")
            name = names(input("How should we call you? ").capitalize())
            name.name_in_use()
        else:
            print(f"Welcome, {self.name}!")


def new_user():
    user_answer = input("Are you a new user? [y/n] ")
    if user_answer == "y":
        name = names(input("How should we call you? ").capitalize())
        name.name_in_use()
    else:
        old_user = input("What is your username? ").capitalize()
        print(f"Welcome, {old_user}!")
        return



new_user()
```

How do I extract local name variable from class if it goes into else under name_in_use()?

I tried so many different ways but once outside of function python doesn't see it.

Comment: Why do you have a class here at all? If a class has two methods, and one of them is `__init__`, it should probably just be a function instead.

Comment: Also, using recursion to implement an infinite (or at least open-ended) loop is a bad idea.

Comment: It's not finished. More function will be added to it later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If an instance of `names` is supposed to use a unique name, that is something that should be enforced either *in* `__init__`, or better yet, before you *call* `__init__`. Use a class method to verify the name first.

```
class Name:
    used_names = {}
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.used_names.add(name)

    @classmethod
    def from_unique_name(cls):
        while True:
            name = input("How should we call you?")
            if name not in used_names:
                break
            print(f"Sorry {name} is already taken. Please come up with a different username.")
        return cls(name)


# Returns an instance of Name or None
def new_user():
    user_answer = input("Are you a new user? [y/n] ")
    if user_answer == "y":
        return Name.from_unique_name()
    else:
        old_user = input("What is your username? ").capitalize()
        if old_user in Name.used_names:
            print(f"Welcome, {old_user}!")
            return Name(old_user)
        else:
            print("No user by the name of {old_user}")


user = new_user()
```

A couple of points to keep in mind:

1. If multiple threads could be creating new users, you should use a lock to make sure only one thread can append to `Name.used_names` at a time, and that no other thread can read from it while another thread is updating it.
2. `new_user` could also be a class method.

Answer (score 0):

I find few problems in your code.

1. `name_in_use` function is recursive with no breaking condition
2. Code is repeating in `new_user` functions as well as `name_in_use` function inside the class
3. Return statements are missing

Here is the code I propose (Not tested but should work fine)

```
from database import usernames


class names():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def name_in_use(self):
        if self.name in usernames:
            print(f"Sorry {self.name} is already taken. Please come up with a different username.")
            return None
        else:
            return self.name


def new_user():
    user_answer = input("Are you a new user? [y/n] ")
    if user_answer == "y":
        while True:
            name = names(input("How should we call you? ").capitalize())
            new_name = name.name_in_use()
            if new_name:
                print(f"Welcome, {new_name}!")
                break
            else:
                user_answer1 = input("You want to try again? [y/n] ")
                if user_answer1 == "n":
                    break
    else:
        old_user = input("What is your username? ").capitalize()
        print(f"Welcome, {old_user}!")
        return
```